# WCF custom serializer

Tags: .net, wcf, json, serialization

I'm creating a web service in WCF that returns JSON, but the DataContractJsonSerializer is balking on some circular references (which I can't remove in this particular case).

Instead, I'd like to use the Newtonsoft json library. What's the easiest way to create a custom serializer in WCF?

Note: I know I could just return a stream, but I don't want operation code aware of serialization stuff.

Answer (score 4):

Re *pure* WCF: if you control both ends of the wire (on "full" .NET), then applying a custom serializer is relatively simple - you add a behaviour inherited from `DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior`, and override `CreateSerializer` - see [here](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/source/browse/trunk/protobuf-net/ServiceModel/ProtoOperationBehavior.cs) (with attribute [here](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/source/browse/trunk/protobuf-net/ServiceModel/ProtoBehaviorAttribute.cs)).

However! My *understanding* (untested) is that a JSON-enabled WCF service won't use this route, but will apply its own serializer directly.

Comment: This nearly works, but my json is getting wrapped in an xml root node, like so:
<root>{"Id":0,"IsFinalized":false,"IsTemplate":false}</root>

Comment: Links appear to be broken.

Comment: Found links [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vsminecraft/tree/master/dependencies/protobuf-net/protobuf-net/ServiceModel)

Answer (score 2):

Set IsReference attribute of DataContract to true, it is available with .NET 3.5SP1

```
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
public class Employee
```

For more details see.
[MSDN DataContractAttribute.IsReference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute.isreference.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Very good article: [XmlSerializer vs DataContractSerializer: Serialization in Wcf](http://www.danrigsby.com/blog/index.php/2008/03/07/xmlserializer-vs-datacontractserializer-serialization-in-wcf/). There Dan Rigsby is showing different scenarios and how to make your own serializer in more detail.

Comment: Link is broken.

Comment: This link works:  http://web.archive.org/web/20130430190551/http://www.danrigsby.com/blog/index.php/2008/03/07/xmlserializer-vs-datacontractserializer-serialization-in-wcf/  ...from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2505801/530545

Answer (score 0):

you can uses ScriptIgnore attribute as mentioned here:-
[Ignoring a field during .NET JSON serialization; similar to [XmlIgnore]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1411577/ignoring-a-field-during-net-json-serialization-similar-to-xmlignore)
Though I am looking forward to implement something like you want, don't want to decorate lot of nested objects