# XML Serialization Error In Nhibernate with MVC4 Web API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, asp.net-web-api

Hello we are creating a web API in MVC4 with NHibernate. But when we are calling the web API it throws us the Error. Here is the Error.

```
<Error><Message>An error has occurred.</Message><ExceptionMessage>The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/xml; charset=utf-8'.</ExceptionMessage><ExceptionType>System.InvalidOperationException</ExceptionType><StackTrace/><InnerException><Message>An error has occurred.</Message><ExceptionMessage>Type 'NHibernate.Collection.Generic.PersistentGenericSet`1[[MvcAngular.Models.BankAccount, MvcAngular, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' with data contract name 'ArrayOfBankAccount:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MvcAngular.Models' is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver or add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.</ExceptionMessage><ExceptionType>System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException</ExceptionType><StackTrace>   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeAndVerifyType(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean verifyKnownType, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, Type declaredType)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeWithXsiType(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle objectTypeHandle, Type objectType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, Type declaredType)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.InternalSerialize(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean isDeclaredType, Boolean writeXsiType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.InternalSerializeReference(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean isDeclaredType, Boolean writeXsiType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
   at WriteCustomerInfoToXml(XmlWriterDelegator , Object , XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext , ClassDataContract )
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.WriteXmlValue(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.WriteDataContractValue(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeWithoutXsiType(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.InternalSerialize(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean isDeclaredType, Boolean writeXsiType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.InternalSerializeReference(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean isDeclaredType, Boolean writeXsiType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
   at WriteArrayOfCustomerInfoToXml(XmlWriterDelegator , Object , XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext , CollectionDataContract )
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContract.WriteXmlValue(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.WriteDataContractValue(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeAndVerifyType(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean verifyKnownType, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, Type declaredType)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeWithXsiTypeAtTopLevel(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle originalDeclaredTypeHandle, Type graphType)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalWriteObjectContent(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalWriteObject(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.WriteObjectHandleExceptions(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.WriteObjectHandleExceptions(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.WriteObject(XmlWriter writer, Object graph)
   at System.Net.Http.Formatting.XmlMediaTypeFormatter.<>c__DisplayClass7.<WriteToStreamAsync>b__6()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpers.RunSynchronously(Action action, CancellationToken token)</StackTrace></InnerException></Error>
```

We are successfully getting the Result in the WebApi. here is the schema of the Classess. we have Used ISET int the parent class

```
public class CustomerInfo
    {

        int _CustomerId;
        public virtual int CustomerId
        {
            get { return _CustomerId; }
            set { _CustomerId = value; }
        }

        string _Name;
        [Required]
        public virtual string Name
        {
            get { return _Name; }
            set { _Name = value; }
        }

        public virtual ISet<BankAccount> BankAccounts { get; set; }


        public virtual void SetBankAccount(ISet<BankAccount> bankact)
        {
            this.BankAccounts = bankact;
        }


        public virtual ISet<BankAccount> GetBankAccounts()
        {
            return this.BankAccounts;
        }

    }
```

AND This is the Get Method of Web API

```
 public IList<CustomerInfo> Get()
        {
            CustomerInfoDAL cd = new CustomerInfoDAL();
            var lst = cd.GetCustomer();
            return lst;
        }
```

We are successfully getting the Result in lst. but while showing that through Web api it shows us this Error.

Comment: The error is because you are, as noted by the inner exception, trying to serialize an internal NHibernate type that the DataContractSerializer knows nothing about. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2551073/how-can-i-transfer-an-nhibernate-persistentgenericset-over-wcf.

Comment: Then should we try Bag instead of SET ? and should we try IList rather than ISET

Comment: Then you will get a PersistentGenericBag instead of a PersistenGenericSet.

Answer (score 0):

Actually Nhibernate ISET<> is not supported by serialization. we have to fetch that though JSON. ie you can use Fiddler to see the result.